# How to make a website without a a website maker

Tags: html, web

I've been wanting to make a website but I wanted to code it myself without using one of those website makers. Are there any ways of doing this? I would also like to publish it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Write your code and save it.
2.Purchase a domain and host it with [ehost](http://ehost.com) or something like that.
3.Upload your file. That's it.

[ehost provide hosting with free domain]

Answer (score 0):

This is not technically an appropriate question for SO. However, you need to learn the basics of HTML. Start at W3 Schools. http://www.w3schools.com

Comment: I already know HTML. I was thinking along the lines of making a website and publishing it.

Comment: Then go get a copy of MAMP (it's free) https://www.mamp.info/en/ make your website and then roll those files to a hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you already know HTML. If you are just making static content, that will suffice. I strongly recommend learning CSS. While it is not technically necessary, it will make your life much easier. When you want to publish it, you will have to pay for a domain and a hosting service. [Google Domains](https://domains.google.com/about/) can help you with this.